# How to get StepExecution in delegated ItemReader in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have created batch application which do chunk processing. I am creating chunks using Completion Policy.

Following is my batch configuration, (keeping code minimal, please let me know if need other information)

```
@Bean
public Job myJob() {
    ItemReader itemReader = itemReader();
    return jobBuilder.get("job").start(myStep(itemReader, completionPolicyReader(itemReader), writer(), processor()));
}

@Bean
public Step myStep(ItemReader itemReader, MyCompletionPolicy completionPolicyReader, ItemWriter writer, ItemProcessor processor) {
    return stepBuilder.get("step").chunk(completionPolicyReader).reader(completionPolicyReader).processor(processor).writer(writer).listener(itemReader).build(); // registered delegated itemReader to listener.
}

@Bean
public MyCompletionPolicy completionPolicyReader(ItemReader itemReader) {
    MyCompletionPolicy obj = new MyCompletionPolicy();
    obj.setDelegate(itemReader);
    return obj;
}

@Bean
public ItemReader itemReader() {
   abc === xyz ? new AReader() : new BReader();
}
// other config
```

Following is my `MyCompletionPolicy` which delegates to actual `ItemReader` ie either `AReader` or `BReader` depending on some condition.

```
class MyCompletionPolicy extends
    CompletionPolicySupport implements ItemReader<MyModel>, StepExecutionListener {

    public void setDelegate(ItemReader<MyModel> itemReader) {
      this.itemReader = itemReader;
      this.delegate = new SingleItemPeekableItemReader<MyModel>();
      this.delegate.setDelegate(itemReader);
    }

    @Override
    public MyModel read() {
      currentReadItem = delegate.read(); // Here I am delegating to actual reader (ex AReader) where I cannot get `StepExecution`
      return currentReadItem;
    }

   .... // Other overridden methods
}
```

Following is my `AReader` where I am not able to get `StepExecution`

```
class AReader  implements ItemReader<MyModel>, StepExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
       // stepExecution is NULL
    }
    .... // other overridden methods
}
```

How I can get stepExecution in my delegated ItemReader ie in AReader.

======EDIT=====

Sub question regarding best practices. If I want to increment count between chunks i.e for example between multiple calls of ItemReader and use current value of counter in ItemReader. Is it good practice to Create class field in ItemReader class or should I store it in ExecutionContext ?

1. Considering SingleThread App
2. Considering MultiThread App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Spring Batch will automatically register your reader/processor/writer as listeners if they implement `StepExecutionListener`. In your case, the reader is `MyCompletionPolicy` which implements `StepExecutionListener` and will be registered as a listener automatically.

However, Spring Batch is not aware that your `MyCompletionPolicy` delegates to another reader, so you need to explicitly register your delegate as a listener in the step.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I tried your suggestion i.e. registered delegated ItemReader (implements StepExecutionListener) as listener in step..still its not calling listener methods ex beforeStep. Will you please also comment on edit section of question.

Comment: The `SimpleStepBuilder#listener()` is overloaded (4 flavors) so make sure the reader is correctly cast to a `StepExecutionListener`. Please edit the question and show how you registered it. In regards to your "sub question", please open another question with an example of what you are trying to achieve, I'll do my best to help.

Comment: I have updated Job config ie first piece of code and added comment where I registered deletgated `ItemReader` to listener. I calls` SimpleStepBuilder listener(Object listener)` overloaded method from 4 methods. I will create another question for edit section as you said. Thank you :)